# Is it better to create a Dockerfile based on tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter or refactor for load_image() attribute?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dockerfile, jupyter

I am developing image classification models in the Jupyter notebook environment. After getting my model to work with the CPU, I am trying to use the latest TensorFlow Docker image supported for Jupyter & GPU ([tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker)) so I can take advantage of my GPU for training. The GPU configuration is not the problem (`nvidia-smi` command shows the GPU is available), but I'm now stuck on what I should do with my image data pipeline setup.

I have folders containing images with the following structure:

```
my_folder
│
└───Training
│   │
│   └───Class_A
│   │       01234.jpg
│   │       56789.jpg
│   │       ...
│   │        
│   └───Class_B
│   │       01234.jpg
│   │       56789.jpg
│   │       ...
│   
└───Validation
│   │
│   └───Class_A
│   │       01234.jpg
│   │       56789.jpg
│   │       ...
│   │        
│   └───Class_B
│   │       01234.jpg
│   │       56789.jpg
│   │       ...
```

```
path_training = 'my_folder/Training/'
path_validation = 'my_folder/Validation/'
image_size = (90, 90)
```

With tensorflow == 2.6.2, I can easily load in my training/validation image datasets with the following code:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(path_training,
                                                               seed=1993, 
                                                               image_size = image_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(path_validation,
                                                             seed=1993,
                                                             image_size = image_size)
```

However, it became apparent that this command does not work when using the Docker image:

> ----> 3 train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(path_training,
> 4                                                                seed=1993,
> 5                                                                image_size = image_size)
>
> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.preprocessing' has no
> attribute 'image_dataset_from_directory'

So I discovered the tensorflow version of the Docker image is 2.1.0, and that attribute is not listed in the API, which leaves me this option:

```
# Read in all image files and split into training/validation sets (tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0)
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(path_training, target_size = image_size)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(path_validation, target_size = image_size)
```

As might be expected, the [load_img()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img) command from TensorFlow 2.1.0 does not read in directories, like image_dataset_from_directory() does.

> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'my_folder/Training/'

I'm not sure what the best or easiest path forward would be here, as I'm not very familiar with building Docker images. Would it be better to build a Dockerfile based on TensorFlow's latest official tensorflow-GPU & Jupyter Docker image so I can utilize `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` or should I just make do with this pre-built Docker image and load my image data with `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img()` by looping through files in the directory path and creating training/validation image datasets this way? For the latter approach, I searched and found [some similar examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89223/keras.preprocessing.image.load_img), notably this example code:

```
def get_data(dir):
    X_train, Y_train = [], []
    X_test, Y_test = [], []
    subfolders = sorted([file.path for file in os.scandir(dir) if file.is_dir()])
    for idx, folder in enumerate(subfolders):
        for file in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):
            img = load_img(folder+"/"+file, color_mode='grayscale')
            img = img_to_array(img).astype('float32')/255
            img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1],1)
            if idx < 35:
                X_train.append(img)
                Y_train.append(idx)
            else:
                X_test.append(img)
                Y_test.append(idx-35)

    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    Y_train = np.array(Y_train)
    Y_test = np.array(Y_test)
    return (X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I gave up on the refactoring approach, but I learned how to build a Docker image! It was surprisingly easier than I anticipated. Now I am able to use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` as well as my GPU for deep learning.

This is basically the Dockerfile I built:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter

ENV python_version 3.8

# Install desired Python version (the current TF image is based on Ubuntu at the moment)
RUN apt install -y python${python_version}

# Set default version for root user 
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python /usr/bin/python${python_version} 1

# Update pip: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-pip-setuptools-and-wheel-are-up-to-date
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8888
```

Here are contents of the basic `requirements.txt` file I used:

```
numpy
matplotlib
pandas
scikit-learn
tensorflow-gpu==2.10.0
```

After importing `tensorflow`, here is the print out of the TensorFlow version as well as what devices are available:

```
print(tf. __version__)
print(tf.config.get_visible_devices())
```

> 2.10.0 [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0',
> device_type='GPU')]

I can then load image datasets easily!

Here are some useful links:

[Setting up TensorFlow with GPU acceleration the quick way](https://blog.softwaremill.com/setting-up-tensorflow-with-gpu-acceleration-the-quick-way-add80cd5c988)

[Installing TensorFlow and Jupyter, with GPU Support](https://sinistercode.com/public/donnie/blog/tensorflow-gpu-jupiter)

For anyone who comes across this post, I hope you find my thought process useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I tried refactoring for the load_img() function from TF 2.1.0:

```
def get_data(dir, set_option):
    if set_option == 'train':
        train_ds = []
        subfolders = sorted([file.path for file in os.scandir(dir) if file.is_dir()])
        for folder in subfolders:
            for file in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):
                img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(folder+"/"+file, color_mode='grayscale')
                train_ds.append(img)
        return train_ds
    elif set_option == 'test':  
        test_ds = []
        subfolders = sorted([file.path for file in os.scandir(dir) if file.is_dir()])
        for folder in subfolders:
            for file in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):
                img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(folder+"/"+file, color_mode='grayscale')
                test_ds.append(img)
        return test_ds
    
train_ds = get_data(path_training, 'train')
test_ds = get_data(path_validation, 'test')
```

Which returns the image datasets as a list with this format:

```
[<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=92x114 at 0x7FE6D11B67B8>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=88x110 at 0x7FE6D11B6898>]
```

However, using the simpler TF 2.6.2 `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` function returns image datasets in this format:

```
<BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 90, 90, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>
```

I've realized that my approach to append images into the list (basically my attempt of image_dataset_from_directory), causes issues for one-hot encoding with the training and validation datasets, as it raises the following AttributeError:

```
one_hot_encoded_train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.one_hot(y, depth=3)))
one_hot_encoded_val_ds = test_ds.map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.one_hot(y, depth=3)))
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

I'm not sure if I'm attempting to create the image dataset objects incorrectly. Regardless, I am thinking using an updated image of TensorFlow may be easier in the long-run considering my difficulty thus far in trying to do without the `image_dataset_from_directory()` function.